# How to solve the paradox of an event that has 99% of occurring but that implies a binary outcome with equal chances (50-50)

Tags: probability, sampling, binary-data

I am trying to explain the paradox of an event that has a 99% probability but is expressed as an outcome that has equal binary chances.  Specifically, a patient has a 99% chance of surviving the surgery and 1% chance of dying.   So surgery looks like a reasonable option.  However, the chances of dying or surviving are either or so the probability expressed as a frequency is 1/2 = 50%.  I am trying to explain it as the set of death or survival having 2 partitions with each having an equal chance of being sampled.  One partition gives 99 survivals, the other gives 1 death.  The equal chance of sampling from each partition reflects the binary outcome of death or survival.  Once we land in a specific partition we add deaths or survivals such that our proportion remains the correct one (99% survival).  Is this a correct interpretation?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just because there are two outcomes does not mean that they are equally likely. Your interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: There are actually *three* possible outcomes: dying after surgery, surviving after surgery, and surviving after surgery on a Tuesday when the moon is full.  By your reasoning, then, the chances of dying would only be $1/3$.

Comment: You both miss the point.  Dying or not dying are the only two options of that sample space.  So the chances of being in one or the other is 1/2.  Once you get in a particular sample space either 99 will survive or 1 will die.  Nobody operates on tuesdays with full moons   because most surgeons react badly to the full moon and tuesdays is the day before wednesday off.  Besides, it adds two more sample spaces each with their own probabilities which although solvable, are not interesting,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [frequentist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability) might put it this way:

> In a group of 100 patients in similar circumstances as the patient before you, 99 survive surgery and 1 dies.

---

In the language of your question. Let $S$ denote the set of patients who underwent surgery, let $D$ denote the number of patients who die as a result of surgery, and let $D^c$ denote the set of survivors. Then the size of $D^c$ is $99$ times the size of $D$: $|D| = \frac{1}{99}|D^c|$.

If you want to see this as a sampling problem and you assume that each patient, $p_i$, is sampled with equal probability, then the probability of sampling a patient who survived is $99 \%$, and $1\%$ for a patient who died.

[So, there is no *"equal chance of sampling from each partition"*. You are far more likely to sample a $p_i$ from $D^c$.]

Comment: That is correct but it does not address the question of "Doctor, what are my chances of surviving this operation?" and the answer is "You have a 99% chance of surviving the operation because the mortality is only 1%; on the other hand your chances of dying or surviving ar 50% because either you die, or you survive".  A Bayesian feels very comfortable in being either "In" the distribution or "Out" of the distribution,  1/2 = 50%.

Comment: @LDBerriz  I expanded the answer to your main question. Commenters Matt and whuber make some good points, which I agree with. Effective communication with patients is another (difficult) question.